# How can I prohibit the creation of a route in Windows XP upon connection to Cisco VPN?

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, routing, vmware-workstation, cisco-vpn-client

**Problem**

I have several routes that are created when I connect to my company's VPN using Cisco VPN client.  (It appears to be a bug in our VPN client that we're subjected to this in the first place: Allow Local LAN Access is ON but the client is ignoring the option.)

I have a virtual machine running on my system that I want to connect to while I'm on the VPN.  I can do this reliably by deleting the route to the network of my VPN's Host-Only adapter created by the vpn client but I have to delete the route every time I connect to my VPN.

**Question**

How do I reliably prohibit either the deletion of these routes either at the time of connection, prohibit some of them from being created, or work around them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I am using the Host-Only VM adapter with set IP addresses on both the host and guest I created a work around as follows:

Add a persistent route from the host to the VM using the following command:

`route -p add <guest-ip-address> 255.255.255.255 <host-vmnet1-ip-address>`

Because this is a more specific route than the 255.255.255.0 route that the VPN software creates, this route is used even when connected to the VPN.