# How to configure ShrewSoft VPN to connect to Cisco VPN Server?

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client, shrew

What are the steps to connect to a Cisco VPN server using the ShrewSoft VPN Client?

It's important to note that there are different kinds of Cisco VPN connections:

1. Cisco VPN with pre-shared key (IPSec)
2. Cisco AnyConnect (SSL VPN)
3. Cisco VPN with a `.pcf` file (IPSec)
4. Cisco VPN with certificate (IPSec)

I have the [detailed answer for `1.`, pre-shared key](http://read-stuff-here.blogspot.com/2009/09/shrew-vpn-tutorial-on-windows-64-bit.html). i will be answering that myself.

I *need* a detailed answer for using ShrewSoft VPN as an alternative to **Cisco AnyConnect**.

I know the [.pcf is easy; you can read about it.](http://read-stuff-here.blogspot.com/2009/09/shrew-vpn-tutorial-on-windows-64-bit.html)

For completeness the certificate version would be good.

Comment: Since the ShrewSoft VPN client is an IPSec client, you aren't going to be able to use it for SSL VPNs (AnyConnect or otherwise).

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do 2?

Comment: I have tried the answer by Ian Boyd and it has worked fine for me so far. Thanks, Ian.

Answer (score 61):

### 1. Cisco VPN with pre-shared key

Assume you have been given connection information for a Cisco VPN server:

> Host: `64.34.199.12`
>
> Group ID: `SUPERVENDOR`
>   Password: `*318#($@`
>
> User ID: `ian@superuser.com`
>   Password: `ianvendor1234`

These are the steps to use ShrewSoft VPN to connect to the Cisco VPN server, rather than the Cisco client:

1. Create a new connection, and under **Host name or IP Address** enter the `Host` address (`64.34.199.12`):
   [image]
2. On the **Authentication tab**, select **Authentication Method** of `Mutual PSK + XAuth`:
   [image]
3. On the **Authentication -> Local Authentication tab** select **Identification Type** of `Key Identifier`:
   [image]
4. Still on the **Authentication -> Local Authentication tab**, enter **Key ID String** of `SUPERVENDOR`:
   [image]
5. On the **Authentication -> Credentials tab**, enter your **Pre Shared Key** of `*318#($@`:
   [image]
6. Save the newly created connection, and click **Connect**
7. When prompted for a username and password, enter your supplied **User ID** and **Password**, and click **Connect**:
   [image]

Comment: What you mean by group id is it group name?

Comment: @alsadk Sure, why not. i'm not the one who decides Cisco's terminology; i'm just the one that wants them dead.

Comment: thanks for answer. I have a problem where the VPN connection is brought up, it looks like I can send data but nothing being routed back. anything that needs to be done windows (firewall) wise?  (windows 8.1 x64) thanks- sam

Comment: Just a note for others -- in my company's setup there is an RSA soft-token.   Upon initial setup the soft token's pin needed to be reset.   The cisco version brought up the reset, the shrewsoft vpn failed with a non descript message.  Once I reset the pin from default, shrewsoft works fine.

Comment: We upgraded a few devices to Win10 and noticed that we couldn't use the old school cisco VPN anymore.  I can verify that this method works 100%.  Thanks a lot for providing this info.