# VPN Client using preshared key for Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn

I read this question already [Alternative to Cisco VPN Client on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954102/alternative-to-cisco-vpn-client-on-windows-10) and it only shows how to install Cisco VPN Client on Windows 10, which does not work anymore since the latest update of Windows 10 by the time this question asked.

I used Cisco VPN Client for some months on Windows 10. However, since the latest Windows 10 update, the program is removed by the Windows. Even though I can see that the process is still running based on the task manager.

I need a similar software like Cisco VPN Client on Windows 10 which has the options to input the Group and User Authentication as shown on this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7urlH.png).

I know Cisco has newer VPN program, Cisco Anyconnect, but it does not have the options to input that information. I also tried FortiClient, SoftEther, and ShrewSoft, but the configuration is much more complex than Cisco VPN Client.

How to configure other VPN Client program to work like Cisco VPN Client for Windows 10? To be able to make a VPN connection using pre-shared key (User ID and Group ID).

**EDIT**

ShrewSoft VPN Client can make a VPN Connection using preshared key as described on this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/312947/how-to-configure-shrewsoft-vpn-to-connect-to-cisco-vpn-server?newreg=2cd8e7ac00654d77a0cc359ec51d36af)

Comment: Software recomendations are specifically not on topic here at Superuser.  Have you tried to simply install the Cisco VPN client?  While its true that normally, if software is removed, it actually is incompatible.  It is worth a try to at least try to install it to verify that fact.

Comment: I already installed Cisco VPN Client before. This software is actually not compatible with Win10, but there is some workaround that you can find on internet. It is exactly the same with the answer on the link I mentioned on my question. but since the last update, it does not work anymore.

Comment: I see no reason, the work around would be verision specific, but if it does not work then you are indeed out of luck on the incompatible software.  With that said, software recomendations are still not on topic here at Superuser, there are SE websites where it is on topic.

Comment: I didn't know that there is actually Software Recommendation SE. Sorry for that. Is it possible to migrate this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem. Probably CISCO VPN will get updated, but until then, I recommend you use **SoftEther VPN Client** because it still works after the latest windows updates.

To fix the **CISCO VPN** compatibility itself, do this:

- Download the vpnclient-winx64-msi-5.0.07.0290-k9.exe (for x64). This can be found online if you don't have it.
- Use 7-Zip to extract the .exe file (vpnclient_setup.msi is what you need from the archive)
- Go to the **Control Panel** --> **Programs** --> **Programs and Features**, find the Cisco Systems VPN Client in the list of programs, and use the **repair** option.
- The repair will ask you for an MSI source, point it to the vpnclient_setup.msi you extracted in Step 2.
- Temporary ignore the "Failed to Enable Virtual Adapter" error.
- To fix this error, go to the Registry key: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CVirtA** and change the **DisplayName** value to **Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows** , because the original naming interferes with the driver detection. Any name should do as long as it has no special characters.

Comment: I believe Cisco VPN client won't be updated based on its official  [website](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/security/vpn-client/tsd-products-support-eol-series-home.html). Thank you for your answer. SoftEther looks promising. Gonna try it later on my Win10 machine and will let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, SoftEther also does not work. I don't really know computer network, but maybe because the server configured with Cisco so it can be only accessed by Cisco VPN Client?

Comment: @weha - Have you confirmed if your Cisco hardware is configured to only accept Cisco VPN clients?

Comment: SoftEther is pretty complex to configure for inexperienced users. Try downloading the exact version of CISCO VPN I've stated in the answer and install it as described.

Comment: @Ramhound honestly I don't know whether the the hardware is configured that way. I'm just the user and only know how to use it, not configure it. Overmind, I was not actually looking for another workaround for Cisco VPN Client, but maybe I can try it later.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your feedback. I'm just curious whether there is another VPN client program, that works like Cisco VPN Client, on Win10 machine. Right now I go back to use my Win7 machine. I will also delete this question if I have to.

Comment: You could just use OpenVPN which is free and should work in almost any scenario, but that one is extremely hard to configure and it's not even close in resemblance with CISCO VPN. Most companies prefer to offer in a commercial manner such solutions.

Comment: @weha - You should not delete questions.  You should improve this question and bring it into scope.  Besides the question cannot be deleted if it has answer that has been upvoted.

Comment: @Ramhound & Overmind I think I found the answer here [link](http://superuser.com/questions/312947/how-to-configure-shrewsoft-vpn-to-connect-to-cisco-vpn-server?newreg=2cd8e7ac00654d77a0cc359ec51d36af)