# GUI tool to manage routes for Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I am trying to add a route to my computer:

```
route add 10.2.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.8.0.8
```

But of course [it never](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/want-ban-an-ip-what-wrong-route-add-command-help-39598842.html) [works](https://superuser.com/questions/284709/how-to-allow-local-lan-access-while-connected-to-cisco-vpn).

Is there a GUI tool that can manage routes for me? Adding routes by selecting gateways and interfaces? Changing metrics by typing them in?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there are a lot of options, let me list some:

- [Net Route View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_route_view.html)

> NetRouteView is a GUI alternative to the standard route utility
>   (Route.exe) of Windows operating system. It displays the list of all
>   routes on your current network, including the destination, mask,
>   gateway, interface IP address, metric value, type, protocol, age (in
>   seconds), interface name, and the MAC address. NetRouteView also
>   allows you to easily add new routes, as well as to remove or modify
>   existing static routes.

- [WinIP Config](http://www.pkostov.com/wipcfg.html)

> Win IP Configuration Manager is a replacement for the annoying command
>   line tools "ipconfig.exe" and "route.exe". This version also includes
>   the "netstat.exe" tool. Win IP Configuration Manager shows you the IP
>   settings of the installed network interfaces. IP addresses obtained by
>   DHCP can be renewed by Win IP Config. Routes can easily be added,
>   removed, changed or made persistent by this tool. Network interfaces
>   can administratively be enabled or disabled, repectively. Throughput
>   statistics can be watched for each of the network interfaces in a
>   separate window. The program has full capabilities with Windows 2000,
>   Windows XP and Windows Vista. Some functions are not supported under
>   Windows 98. Windows ME should behave like Windows 98, but this has not
>   been tested.

Moreover, I still think the best way is following a [good guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/) to do it(even using a GUI tool) because there are a lot of details to pay attention on changing routes.

Comment: Accepted for NirSoft; is there any tool they didn't create.

Comment: Bonus points to NetRoute for not needing to be installed

Comment: Link to the good guide is dead.