# Split Tunnel and Cisco AnyConnect

Tags: vpn, cisco-anyconnect, split-tunnel

I am using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.1.02026 on Windows 7 64-bit.  I have heard there is a checkbox which enables split tunneling.  However, this checkbox is removed from the GUI probably due to the administrator's settings.  The administrator doesn't want to make any configuration changes.  I would like to force split tunneling.  How?  It's okay if the solution uses a different VPN client.  The solution can not make any changes on the VPN server.  I have tried a virtual machine and it works, but I would like a more convenient solution.  I have tried messing around with route table but I failed probably due to lack of knowing how to do it right.

Here is my `route print` before connecting to the VPN.

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 14...00 1e 4f d7 64 5b ......Intel(R) 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 25...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 27...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.3     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.3     11
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
      192.168.1.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0      192.168.1.3       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.154.128.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 27     58 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 27     58 2001::/32                On-link
 27    306 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:3431:3b25:b736:1859/128
                                    On-link
 14    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 27    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 27    306 fe80::3431:3b25:b736:1859/128
                                    On-link
 14    266 fe80::3933:bb6f:892:d161/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 27    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Here is my `route print` after connecting to the VPN.

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 19...00 05 9a 3c 7a 00 ......Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
 14...00 1e 4f d7 64 5b ......Intel(R) 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 25...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 27...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
167...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.3     10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.154.128.1     10.154.159.8      2
     10.154.128.0    255.255.224.0         On-link      10.154.159.8    257
     10.154.159.8  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.154.159.8    257
   10.154.159.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.154.159.8    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     137.254.4.91  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.3     11
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      10.154.159.8    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.3    306
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.154.159.8    257
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
      192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3     11
      192.168.1.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.154.159.8    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.154.159.8    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0      192.168.1.3       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.154.128.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 19     11 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 19    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 19    266 fe80::2a78:5341:7450:2bc1/128
                                    On-link
 14    266 fe80::3933:bb6f:892:d161/128
                                    On-link
 19    266 fe80::c12f:601f:cdf:4304/128
                                    On-link
 19    266 fe80::c5c3:8e03:b9dd:7df5/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/284709/how-to-allow-local-lan-access-while-connected-to-cisco-vpn

Answer (score 11):

First understand that the reason your network admins have disallowed split tunneling is because it potentially allows any malicious person/code to circumvent the security measures that have been implemented by accessing the network via your computer.  Believe me I know not having a split tunnel is annoying, but ask your self is it worth the risk?

Now that warnings are out of the way I can tell you Cisco AnyConnect prevents a split tunnel by temporarily re-writing the routing table of the host computer.  Use `route print` before you start AnyConnect and use it again after to see the differences.  You can write a script to adjust the routing table and run it after you start AnyConnect.  An easier solution that probably doesn't violate your networks usage policy is simply using a VM with AnyConnect.  Your host's NIC doesn't get locked down and you don't break any rules... best of both worlds.

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect prevents route adjustments on Windows from working.

Comment: Using a VM is the easiest way indeed. In Virtualbox, use Bridge mode.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out how to split tunnel with Cisco AnyConnect.  Here's my work around.

I tried using VPNC Front End but a generic error message prevented me from fixing the connection settings.  I needed to add "Application version Cisco Systems VPN Client 4.8.01 (0640):Linux" into default.conf.  Also, once the connection was established, I couldn't access anything in the remote LAN.  I needed to create a batch file which added routes for the remote LAN IP addresses (e.g. `route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.85.37.1 metric 9 IF 180`). The same batch file also had to configure to use the remote LAN's DNS servers first before my ISP's DNS servers (e.g. `netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Local Connection 2" 42.23.24.46 index=1`)

To get a more detailed error message, I followed the instructions on [BMC](http://discovery.bmc.com/community/blog-post/cisco-vpn-under-windows-without-using-the-cisco-vpn-client/).  I had to install additional packages: Net openssl, Devel Libs openssl-devel and Interpreters perl.

Answer (score 0):

Although this won't help someone who's trying to get around the security placed on the ASA by an administrator, for someone who IS an ASA administrator, Cisco has this article, on setting up the ASA and Anyconnect with split tunnel access:

[Configure AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client with Split Tunneling on an ASA](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/119006-configure-anyconnect-00.html)